# Swagger call fails - net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have defined swagger for REST APIs. Swagger explorer is working fine. 1 of the APIs is doing bulk update of dynamo DB records. It takes around 3-4 minutes to complete dynamoDB operation. For this API, swagger call runs for sometime and then it says

```
Response Code
0
Response Headers
{
  "error": "no response from server"
}
```

When I checked logs, there is no any exception from swagger. This API update operation runs in background and completes processing in 3-4 minutes. I have verified it using logs and metric datapoint. I want swagger also to pause/ continuous active load instead of getting timed out.

After checking Inspect part of page, it says

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Is there any way to update swagger timeout/ anything?

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Helen net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE